# Install latest python on Core

Tags: python, snap, ubuntu-core

I have a blank install of ubuntu core and am trying to install python.

I have tried the following

```
snap install python
snap install python3
snap install --edge python
```

I receive `error: snap "python" not found`

I have trawled through other answers about using "classic", etc. which didn't seem to work for me anyway.

I cannot seem to find any straight forward instructions, any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snaps can have *almost* no dependencies (just `core` and a GUI interface). Python is not one of those dependencies.

A snap-provided application that uses Python under the hood should NOT assume that a system-provided Python is available, and is expected to include its own Python inside the snap (rather like LibreOffice includes its own Python).

- This is COMPLETELY different from the way deb-based releases of Ubuntu work. Deb-based applications and services share a single standard root-owned, apt-provided Python stack.

Therefore, there is no real need for a "python snap". That's why you cannot find one. Python users can download and install *unpackaged* Python of any version they like from upstream .

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense to a subject that is proving quite confusing thus far. Do you have any recommendations for a good place to learn more about Core, I'm finding https://ubuntu.com/core/docs to be a little too wordy to get my head around. TYIA!

Comment: Please open new Questions for elements of Ubuntu Core that are confusing or have unclear documentation.